# Cherrypy Session Timeout questions

Tags: python, cherrypy

Two questions regarding session timeouts in cherrypy:

1) Is there a way to determine the remaining time in a session? This is related to trying to use http://plugins.jquery.com/epilgrim.sessionTimeoutHandler/

2) Is there a way to make a call to cherrypy NOT reset the timeout, such that the plugin above could call a URL to determine the time remaining in the session without resetting said time

Edit to help clarify: The purpose here is to be able to have a client-side process that periodically queries the server via AJAX to determine the amount of time left in a users session. This is to overcome difficulties with keeping a client side session timeout timer in-sync with the server-side timer - I'd like to simply have the client ask the server "how much time do I have left?" and act accordingly. Of course, if the act of asking resets the timeout, then this won't work, as the AJAX "time left" requests would essentially become a session keep-alive. So I need to be able to make an AJAX query to the server without resetting the session timeout timer for the user.

Answer (score 1):

I believe cherrypy uses the expiration time in the cookie with the key session_id.  Mine says:

```
Wed 22 Jan 2014 03:44:31 PM EST
```

You could extend the expiration with your set of circumstances and edit the session cookie.

EDIT: You will also need to extend the server timeout...

```
cherrypy.request.config.update({'tools.sessions.timeout': 60})
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cherrypy-users/2yrG79QoYFQ

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes the expiration is in the cookie.. http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/lib/sessions.html#cherrypy.lib.sessions.expire

Comment: This helps, but doesn't address point 2: preventing the timeout from being reset. Unless you are saying that explicitly setting the expiration time of the session_id key in the returned cookie will change the timeout? So if I wanted someone to have an extra long timeout, I could simply set this to some far future value after each call?

Comment: That's correct.  Extending expiration of the cookie will extend the expiration of the server side session data.

Comment: Not sure how you did it. By default, expired sessions are deleted every 5 mins by a cleanup thread. Also when a session is loaded for a request, expiration time is checked.

Comment: "CherryPy defaults to a 60-minute session timeout"  http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/lib/sessions.html#expiration-dates clean_freq will run every 5 mins by default to clear sessions that are older than 60 mins.  You can also set: tools.sessions.timeout = 2880  in the config file

Comment: Here's how to extend server side sessions: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cherrypy-users/2yrG79QoYFQ  Warning! this will apply to all user's sessions!

Comment: @AndrewKloos I mean I understand how to change the timeout on the server, but you said changing exp of the cookie will change exp of the server session, and I don't think that is correct.

Comment: @jwalker You're right you'd need to extend the server session timeout too.  I've edited my answer to include that aspect.

Comment: Except I don't want to change the timeout - rather, I want to keep the remaining time in the session from updating. That is, say sessions have the default 60 minute timeout, and the user has been idle for 30 minutes. I want to be able to call a function that can determine there is 30 minutes left in their session, without resetting that to 60 minutes - i.e  a client side timer that can check the timeout status without changing the timeout status

Comment: I see.  Well you could take the expiration of their last submitted cookie and compare the time with your server timeout.

Comment: @AndrewKloos That is not gonna work if other request updates the session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass the session and add a "stats" function to it and a flag to prevent saving in the session "stats" request handler. Or disable sessions in the config for the "stats" path and load session exp info directly from your storage without using normal session class.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to 2) question while going through source code of cherrypy session class. Apparently, you do not want to save session after serving such requests - this will then also not update expiration time (and will not save any changes to session object).

I found in the source code that setting `cherrypy.serving.request._sessionsaved = True` does exactly that. And added decorator for convinience:

```
def nosessionsave( func ):
"""
Decorator to avoid session saving and thus not resetting session timeout.
"""
def decorate( *args, **data ):
    cherrypy.serving.request._sessionsaved = True
    return func( *args, **data )
return decorate
```

Just add `@nosessionsave` before method def.